# Cannot find module 'umi'

Tags: umijs

I just start to learn umijs so, when I try to start (npm start ) then it saw error (Cannot find module 'umi')

> Cannot find module 'umi'
> Require stack:

- E:\Umijs\myapp.umirc.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the dependencies first:

```
$ npm install
```

Refer to this documentation page to environment setup:

https://umijs.org/docs/getting-started